# How to train a custom entity extraction model with Google MLkit?

Tags: android, ios, google-mlkit, named-entity-extraction

I want to train a custom entity extraction model with google mlkit, and use it across android and ios platform. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Google ML kit currently only offers support for [custom image classification models](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models).